# Font awesome icon in Vue.js does not display

Tags: css, vue.js, font-awesome

I am trying to add a font-awesome arrow icon via my css code like this:

```
<style>
.negative {
  color: red;
}

.positive {
  color: green;
}

.negative::after {
  content: "\f106";
 }
</style>
```

I have font-awesome included in my html via CDN. For some reason my icon does not display properly, it just shows a square. Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

Here is the rest of my code, showing the logic behind the displaying of percentages:

```
<template>
<div>
 <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="rowsToDisplay"
      :hide-default-footer="true"
      class="primary"
    >
      <template #item.thirtyDaysDiff="{ item }">
            <span :class="item.thirtyDaysDiffClass">{{ item.thirtyDaysDiff }}%</span>
            
      </template>
      <template #item.sevenDaysDifference="{ item }">
            <span :class="item.sevenDaysDiffClass">{{ item.sevenDaysDiff }}%</span>
            
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        bitcoinInfo: [],
        isPositive: false,
        isNegative: false,
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Currency',
            align: 'start',
            value: 'currency',
          },
          
          { text: '30 Days Ago', value: '30d' },
          { text: '30 Day Diff %', value: 'thirtyDaysDiff'},
          { text: '7 Days Ago', value: '7d' },
          { text: '7 Day Diff %', value: 'sevenDaysDifference' },
          { text: '24 Hours Ago', value: '24h' },
        ],
      }
    },

    methods: {
      
      getBitcoinData() {
        axios
      .get('data.json')
      .then((response => {

      var convertedCollection =  Object.keys(response.data).map(key => {
            return {currency: key, thirtyDaysDiff: 0, sevenDaysDifference: 0,  ...response.data[key]}
          })
          this.bitcoinInfo = convertedCollection
          
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
        },

       
      calculateDifference(a, b) {
      let calculatedPercent = 100 * Math.abs((a - b) / ((a + b) / 2));
      return Math.max(Math.round(calculatedPercent * 10) / 10, 2.8).toFixed(2);
    },

       getDiffClass(a, b) {
      return a > b ? 'positive': a < b ? 'negative' : ''
     },

     
       calculateSevenDayDifference(item) {

         let calculatedPercent = 100 * Math.abs((item['24h'] - item['7d']) / ((item['24h'] + item['7d']) / 2));
      return Math.max(Math.round(calculatedPercent * 10) / 10, 2.8).toFixed(2);
       }
      },
         computed: {
    rowsToDisplay() {
      return Object.keys(this.bitcoinInfo)
        .map(key => {
          return {
            currency: key,
            ...this.bitcoinInfo[key]
          }
        }).map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          thirtyDaysDiff: this.calculateDifference(item['7d'], item['30d']),
          thirtyDaysDiffClass: this.getDiffClass(item['7d'], item['30d']),
          sevenDaysDiff: this.calculateDifference(item['24h'], item['7d']),
          sevenDaysDiffClass: this.getDiffClass(item['24h'], item['7d']),
        }))
    }
  },
      mounted() {
        this.getBitcoinData()
      }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to import your icons inside the template area with `<i ...></i>`?

here is an working example. Check out the [cdn.fontawesome/help-page](https://cdn.fontawesome.com/help) to get more information.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data () {
    return {
      isPositive: false,
      isNegative: true
    }
  }
}).mount('#demo')
```

```css
.negative {
  color: red;
}

.positive {
  color: green;
}

.neutral {
 color: #666;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="demo">    
 <i class="fas" :class="isPositive ? 'fa-angle-up positive' : isNegative ? 'fa-angle-down negative' : 'fa-minus neutral' "></i> 
 <br>
 <br>
 <button @click="isPositive = !isPositive; isNegative = !isNegative" v-text="'change pos and neg'" />
</div>
```

so basically you'll bind the icon classes to your own conditions. You could write the conditions for example with the tenary operator into your template area. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: If I use them in the template they work, but I need them to be loaded via the css because I need an up arrow in case I have the positive class is set and a downwards arrow in case the class is negative

Comment: you have all freedom with vue.js. Why do you don't work with conditions?

Comment: I updated my question with my full code, because the way that I have set up my color change I don't see how I can show the icons in the template with conditions

Comment: could you use my example?

Answer (score 0):

Host Fontawesome yourself by following the steps in this Fontawesome documentation.

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts

i hope this help.